# How can I activate a virtual env with pyenv?

Tags: python, macos, python-venv, pyenv

I followed [this guide](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) to install `pyenv` in order to manage all Python versions I have installed on my Mac. However, it is not clear to me what the `pyenv global 3.7.3` command does and how I can activate a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) that uses Python 3.7. If I type:

```
pyenv version
```

Output:

```
3.7.3
```

But apparently this is not enough to activate the *venv*.

Comment: Maybe you might take a look at native venv. Can be create using "python3 -m venv ." Dot can be replaced with your desired path to install virtual environment

Comment: Your tutorial says nothing about the activation of the virtual environment

Comment: It's explained [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#switch-between-python-versions).

Answer (score 34):

List Python versions in the terminal:

```
pyenv install --list | grep " 3\.[678]"
```

Install Python version if not in list:

```
pyenv install 3.8.6
```

Create a virtual env with a Python version:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.6 project1
```

List versions of virtual environments:

```
pyenv versions
```

Activate a virtual version:

```
pyenv activate project1
```

Comment: How to verify python version that used by the pyenv ?

Comment: @MohammadReza pyenv which python

Comment: bit confused virtualenv and activate are not recognised ....

Comment: @cs0815 You have to install the pyenv-virtualenv plugin. With Homebrew, you can use `brew install pyenv-virtualenv`.

Answer (score 12):

1. ```
   pyenv global 3.7.3
   ```

   sets the global version of Python to 3.7.3. It means that if you decide to use
   Python on your machine without using a virtual environment, then the version 3.7.3 is going to be used as a default.
2. In order to activate the virtual environment use

   ```
   pyenv activate <name>
   ```

   and to deactivate the virtual environment use

   ```
   pyenv deactivate
   ```
3. For more details check, this link https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

If you're using virtualenv, just type

`pyenv virtualenvs`

Then to activate a particular env

`pyenv activate [name]`

Answer (score 0):

If pyenv lists an error when using any commands for example:

`pyenv: no such command 'activate'`

check if you have pyenv-virtualenv package installed. Universal command to install:

`git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv`